# renderURL not working on MVCPortlet jsp page

Tags: jsp, model-view-controller, liferay, portlet, servletexception

Hi Iam building a MVCPortlet on liferay .
 I use a view.jsp that point to two other jsp pages using renderURL but whenever i click on one of the two link i experience an Exception in eclipse console.

here is the code of the view.jsp of the portlet

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<!--<jsp:include page="addNewWebSite.jsp" /> -->

<portlet:renderURL var="addNewWebSite">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/addNewWebSite.jsp"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
<portlet:renderURL var="listWebSites">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/listWebSites.jsp"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
<ul>
<li><a href="<%=addNewWebSite%>">Add new web site</a></li>
<li><a href="<%=listWebSites %>">List Web Site</a></li>
</ul>
```

i have also two file addNewSite.jsp and listWebSites.jsp residing in same directory of the portlet project

here is the stack trace.

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Le fichier &quot;/addNewWebSite.jsp&quot; n'a pas été trouvé
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:412)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:331)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:112)
    ... 167 more
14:18:29,497 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-25][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
```

Comment: Are you having jsp files directly under docroot folder? If not, then keep jsps there

Comment: thanks i figured what was the problem. the jsp file were in docroot/html/portlet_name/; so i put /html/portlet_name/jsp_page in value of the renderURL tag so it worked!

Comment: Also, you might want to use mvcPath instead of jspPage - jspPage is deprecated in favor of mvcPath.

Answer (score 1):

Nwawel, I believe the problem happens in the `<portlet:param>` tag.

In MVCPortlet, if you want to call a JSP page directly from another JSP page, you have to name the the portlet:param's name as "mvcPath", say:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="varA">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/a.jsp"/>
</portlet:renderURL>

<portlet:renderURL var="varB">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/b.jsp"/>
</portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%=varA %>">Link to A</a>
<a href="<%=varB %>">Link to B</a>
```

This will work fine.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your renderURL you are calling the `addNewWebSite.jsp` but your file is named `addNewSite.jsp`
The exception shows that `addNewWebSite.jsp` doesn't exist.

Adjust the name of wich one and then try again.

You have set the render-param, pointing to the "/addNewWebSite.jsp", but you said the name of your file is "addNewSite.jsp", so, the render is looking for "addNewWebSite.jsp", but can't find it, because in the folder there is "addNewSite.jsp".